# Select results based on multiple 'between' criteria

Tags: mysql

The following works fine in my C# program:

```
string dbSQL = "SELECT stationID, stationLatitude, stationLongitude FROM stations_noaa" +
               " WHERE stationLatitude BETWEEN " + LatLow + " AND " + LatHi +
               " INTERSECT " +
               "SELECT stationID, stationLatitude, stationLongitude FROM stations_noaa" +
               " WHERE stationLongitude BETWEEN " + LongLow + " AND " + LongHi;
```

I did invest quite a bit of time trying to get the multiple between criteria in one `SELECT` statement before settling on this. Is it possible?

Comment: Just `AND`ing them? And maybe a `DISTINCT` if the deduplicating effect of `INTERSECT` is desired and needed (assuming that `stationid` is a key, it isn't). And as a side note, you should look into parameterized queries.

Comment: this pattern is what we see in code that is vulnerable to SQL Injection.  not at all clear why we would need `INTERSECT` set operator, why not just `... WHERE t.lat BETWEEN :val1 AND :val2 AND t.long BETWEEN :val3 AND :val4` ... if the goal is to remove duplicates from the resultset, we could add a `GROUP BY` clause or add the `DISTINCT` keyword

Comment: MySQL do not support INTERSECT.

Comment: MySQL does support intersect: https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-intersect/. I am looking for the duplicates only. & thanks for pointing out the parameter issue

Comment: I thought the `WHERE @stationLat BETWEEN 80 AND 90 AND @stationLong BETWEEN 100 AND 110` would work, it did not

Comment: The link you shared said _"Note that MySQL does not support the INTERSECT operator. This tutorial introduces you to how to emulate the INTERSECT operator in MySQL using join clauses."_

Comment: Well I’m very glad I posted. I’ve got 150k rows and would have been none the wiser. Darn pseudo-code